# Loop through first row and if Cell Value = "Item Cost" then loop through that column and carry out subtotal in blanks

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Very new to VBA but have managed to learn a lot in the last few weeks and stitch together some code for a project at work.

I am struggling with a loop within a loop.

Essentially I want to find every column in Row 1 that has cell value of "Item Cost" then loop down through each row in that column and place a subtotal in the blanks.

Any help with a solution would be greatly appreciated.  It is part of a much larger project but I am at this sticking Point.

Code:
[VBA]

```
 Sub InsertTotals()


 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Dim rw As Range
 Dim RowCount As Integer

 RowCount = 0

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 For Each rw In sh.Rows

 If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "Item Cost" Then

    Dim ThisCell As Range
    Dim MySum As Double

    Set ThisCell = rw.offset(-1)

nxt:

Do While ThisCell <> ""
    MySum = MySum + ThisCell
    Set ThisCell = ThisCell.offset(1, 0)
Loop

ThisCell.Value = MySum

If ThisCell.offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Set ThisCell = ThisCell.offset(1, 0)
    MySum = 0
    GoTo nxt
End If
End If


Next rw

End Sub
```

[VBA]

Comment: This code appears very inefficient to me for a simple task like that. You are essentially looping through your entire worksheet twice. How long does it take to execute a single run? You might be able to achieve your goal without VBA by using the SUBTOTAL() worksheet function

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the way that the start and stop of the ranges to be subtotaled were collected. Additionally, every row has a subtotal at the bottom since there is likely an empty cell there.

```
Sub Insert_SubTotals()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long, srw As Long, col As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    With sh
        For col = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If .Cells(1, col) = "Item Cost" Then
                srw = 2
                For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    If IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, col)) And rw > srw Then
                        '.Cells(rw, col).Value = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(srw, col), .Cells(rw - 1, col)))
                        .Cells(rw, col).Formula = "=SUM(" & .Cells(srw, col).Address(0, 0) & _
                                    Chr(58) & .Cells(rw - 1, col).Address(0, 0) & ")"
                        .Cells(rw, col).NumberFormat = _
                          "[color5]_($* #,##0.00_);[color9]_($* (#,##0.00);[color15]_("" - ""_);[color10]_(@_)"
                        srw = rw + 1
                    End If
                Next rw
            End If
        Next col
    End With

    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

I applied a blue *Accounting* style number format to distinguish the subtotals from the rest of the numbers. Modify that as you see fit. The subtotals remain as `=SUM(...)` formulas. I've added (and commented) a line that would simply leave the values just above the formula assignment.